# Getting "FATAL: role "root" does not exist" when trying to do "docker up"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker

I'm starting to work with an existing Rails project that uses Docker. I've used Rails for a long time but never Docker.

After I do a `docker build .` I try to do a `docker-compose up`, but I get:

> FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
>   /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:661:in `rescue in connect': FATAL:  role "root" does not exist (ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError)

It seems to me that the Docker machine is probably trying to connect to the database as the `root` user, but there's no role called `root`, so the connection is rightly failing.

The thing I don't know is why Docker is apparently trying to connect to the database as `root` and how to get it to use the right user.

Here's my `database.yml`:

```
development:
  database: my_app_development
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
```

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: here's my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
web:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - .:/my_app
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  links:
    - postgres
    - redis
    - mailcatcher
  env_file:
    - 'config/application.yml'
postgres:
  image: postgres:9.4
  ports:
    - "5432"
  env_file:
    - 'config/database.yml'
redis:
  image: redis:3.0.6
mailcatcher:
  image: schickling/mailcatcher
  ports:
    - "1080:1080"
```

Comment: How does your docker-compose.yml look like? Are you using a separate container for postgres?

Comment: Hey Lekan! I've edited my answer to include `docker-compose.yml`. I don't know how to know if I'm using a separate container for PostgreSQL.

Comment: Yea Jase! So it appears you are using different containers from your docker-compose.yml. What I think you will have update the compose file with the env vars for postgres.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Dumb question: how do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

You might want to update your compose and database yml as follows. With the expected db user and password in the `database.yml`. Also, you can make this is an environment variable. But try the default for the postgres db docker image first as follows;

`database.yml`

```
development:
  database: my_app_development
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password:
  host: postgres(db name in docker-compose.yml)
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
      web:
        build: .
        command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
        volumes:
          - .:/my_app
        ports:
          - "3000:3000"
        links:
          - postgres
          - redis
          - mailcatcher
      postgres:
        image: postgres:9.4
        ports:
          - "5432"
      redis:
        image: redis:3.0.6
      mailcatcher:
        image: schickling/mailcatcher
        ports:
            - "1080:1080"
```

I dont think you want to keep

```
   env_file:
      - 'config/database.yml'
```

and

```
   env_file:
      - 'config/application.yml'
```

Then create the databases with `docker-compose run web rake db:create`

I added the command instruction because I dont know what your `Dockerfile` looks like. But if you have a successful build of the app image with `docker build -t app-name .`, you can remove it and just run `docker-compose up`.

Answer (score 4):

Postgres image expects `POSTGRES_USER`, `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` and `POSTGRES_DB` to be provided. Otherwise it will use default values. Create a `.env` file in the root directory of your project:

```
# .env file
POSTGRES_USER=testuser
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=testpass
POSTGRES_DB=db_development
```

and change you `docker-compose` file as:

```
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/my_app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
      - mailcatcher
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.4
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    env_file: .env
  redis:
    image: redis:3.0.6
  mailcatcher:
    image: schickling/mailcatcher
    ports:
      - 1080:1080
```

You could also provide the environment variables without `.env` file:

```
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/my_app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
      - mailcatcher
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.4
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=testuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=testpass
      - POSTGRES_DB=db_development
  redis:
    image: redis:3.0.6
  mailcatcher:
    image: schickling/mailcatcher
    ports:
      - 1080:1080
```

and update your `database.yml` file:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: postgres
development:
  <<: *default
  database: db_development
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db_test
production:
  <<: *default
  database: db_production
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 25 } %>
```

WARNING: Don't use `links`, [it'll be removed soon](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links)

Answer (score 2):

Without an explicit user set in the `database.yml` it will attempt to use the `root` user as this is the same user postgres is running under in the container. To fix this, try setting your `database.yml` as:

```
development:
  database: my_app_development
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
```

Note the addition of the **username** field.

Answer (score 2):

With docker-compose, it tries to preserve volumes between runs; since the user is only created on a new database, you probably need to `docker-compose rm -v database` to delete the container and associated volume.

And try `docker-compose up --build` again.

Source: https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/41#issuecomment-167603905